# how to implement img_to_array from tf.keras on javascript especially on react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, keras, expo

I'm new to machine learning and trying to load a machine learning model on React native expo. the model is loaded (I think(?)), so now I try to load the image to the model. while on the google colab it is preprocess as

```
 img = image.load_img(path, target_size =(150,150))
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])

  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
```

I tried to find out how to do the img_to_array from tf.keras.util.image, I did find some functions such as np.array()  but they return different values. is there any how I can implement this on my React native expo projects?